# Install sql-spark-connector library to Azure Synapse Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse

I am trying to install the Apache Spark Connector for SQL Server and Azure SQL to use transactional data in big data analytics and persists results for ad-hoc queries or reporting. The connector allows you to use any SQL database, on-premises or in the cloud, as an input data source or output data sink for Spark jobs.

The spark sql connector is located here https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector

Can someone let me know how to import it in Azure Synapse Apache Spark?

Answer (score 0):

As per the conversation with Synapse Product Group:

> You don’t need to add the connector [Apache Spark connector](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector) jar files or any package `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark` to your Synapse Spark pool. The connector is there out of the box for **Spark 2.4** and for **Spark 3.1** it will be in production most likely in **upcoming weeks**.

For more details, refer to the [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/573544/how-to-install-the-package-commicrosoftsqlserverjd.html) thread which addressing similar issue.

Comment: I was wondering if you'll have time to share your thoughts on a similar question I posted  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72060933/1232087)