# Apache Spark Connector - where to install on Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

This [Apache Spark connector: SQL Server & Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15) article from Azure team describes how to use this connector.

**Question**: If you want to use the above connector in `Azure Databricks`, where will you install it?

**Remarks**: The above article tells you to install it from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector) and import it in, say, your notebook using `com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0`. But it does not tell you where to install. I'm probably not understanding the article correctly. I need to use it in an `Azure Databricks` and would like to know where to install the connector jar (compiled) file.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the cluster setup. See this documentation: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/28/using-3rd-party-libraries-in-databricks-apache-spark-packages-and-maven-libraries.html

In short, when setting up the cluster, you can add third party libraries by their Maven coordinates - "com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0" is an example of a Maven coordinate.